# Convert a mask image to polygon shapefile using GRASS

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis, remote-sensing, classification, masking

I used image classification technique in GRASS GIS v7 and generated the image mask below in which white area has NULL value and red area contains 1.

[image]

I am going to clip those red color areas in a LiDAR file so I need to convert those to a polygon shapefile. I know that I need to use a combination of image analysis techniques to achieve this but don't know whether GRASS has similar functionality to generate polygon shapefile from a mask.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the `r.to.vect` module?
You find the documentation here: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.to.vect.html

Comment: This isn't useful as I need only polygon shapes not points or lines. my sesong question is: let's say I have an ASCII file including rows of X Y Z coordinates. Is there any command in GRASS that I could use to add another column attribute to the ASCII file (let's call it "H") and get its values from the mask (as shown above in raster format). Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see. What about a GDAL alternative? http://gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html

Comment: Werbrian,I used that command and that worked. However, I ended up with large number of polygons so I decided to solve the problem in another way, which is what I posted yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding webrian's answer, the "feat=area" option to r.to.vect will create only polygons.

As for adding a column to your ASCII file, you'll need to import it into grass as a vector, then using v.what.rast you will upload raster values to each point. Something like:

```
v.db.addcolumn <your_vector_layer> column="h double precision"
v.what.rast <your_vector_points> raster=<your_raster_layer> column="h"
```

Now, if you need the data as an ASCII file, export back out. (v.out.ascii)

Comment: Is the "feat=area" option the same as the "type=area"? I'm just asking since I can't find the "feat" option in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, in v7.0 the syntax is now "type=area". (In the previous v6.4 it was "feature=area")

Comment: Hi Micha,I tried to run v.db.addcolumn but I got the message "ERROR: There is no table connected to this map. Run v.db.connect or v.db.addtable first." I thought when I import an ASCII with X Y Z structure, GRASS generates a table and attached it to the resulting vector map. Then in the v.db.addtable, I have to define "columns". My question is after defining columns (let's say X Y Z) in v.db.addtable, how do I assign the actual x, y and z values to the table?

Comment: The `v.in.ascii` import creates a table only when it is "necessary", that is, only when there are additional data columns, other than x-y. If you have defined the x-y-z columns then do `v.to.db` with the parameters: `option=coor columns="x,y,z"`.

Comment: Hi,
I am confused. As I said in my previous posts, I want to import a text file, add another column (to get the structure of x y z status) and populate the “status” attribute from a raster map. The data type of “status” will be int.
I followed the following steps. First I ran: v.in.ascii -n input= pts.txt output=pts_vecorMap separator=’space’. File is read Ok. Then I run the following command: v.to.db map=pts_vecorMap@PERMANENT type=point option=coor columns='x,y,z' 
but I got ERROR: Unable to open database <D:\Astron\Grass\TextFileTest\PERMANENT\sqlite\sqlite.db> by driver <dbf>

Comment: Micha: based on what you said, I should have the table after running v.in.ascii because I have three columns of X Y Z. I don’t where things go wrong. This is a simple thing to do. Could that be because I use windows version of GRASS?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. v.in.ascii does **not** create any table at all, (unless you have additional columns other than the coordinates). After importing the pts.txt, try running: `v.db.addtable pts_vecorMap columns="x double precision, y double precision, z double precision, status integer"` then do the `v.to.db` command as above.